# Should users have the option to hide reputation counts while surfing SO?

Tags: discussion

I realized the other day that I do not browse SO without mentally noting the rep of other users. To mentally check rep for any user who comments, asks, or answers on SO quickly becomes automatic. Right now your are probably thinking: "well..... duh!" But is that helpful? I would like to be able to browse SO without knowing other user's reputation counts.

We all can probably deduce the general skill level of a given user by simply reading their stuff. The option to use the site-- while hiding the reputation-- would be sort of nice. It would remove some bias from my perspective and possibly allow me to be a better participant with respect to voting.

Clearly, reputation is important but the option to hide it from view with a mouse click would be cool. What do you think?

Comment: You can write a user script if you want this. I don't think this needs to be a built in option. In fact someone has done this here http://stackapps.com/questions/3105/hide-all-pointless-user-data-gravatar-badges-and-reputation

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh.. fantastic! I had no idea this sort of modification was even possible. Thank you.

Comment: Though to be clear this does depend on what browser you use and if it has support for a user script extension.

Comment: @MartinSmith In that case, one could argue that this simple option would be a nice addition. Not requisite, of course, and maybe not worth the effort to implement on the part of those who manage this site.